# Restricting access to DynamoDB using tag key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-iam

i'm following Amazon's documentation  for '[Controlling Access to AWS Resources Using Resource Tags](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_tags.html#access_tags_control-tag-keys)'
to control access to my DynamoDB resource using a tag key on the Dynamo table itself.

The policy's Json i use looks like this:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "TestAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:PutItem",
                "dynamodb:DeleteItem",
                "dynamodb:GetItem",
                "dynamodb:Scan",
                "dynamodb:Query",
                "dynamodb:UpdateItem"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "ForAnyValue:StringEquals": {
                    "aws:TagKeys": "X"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

No matter what i do it doesn't seem to allow access using `ForAnyValue`, tried using `StringEquals`/`StringLike` and nothing worked. When i switched to `ForAllValues` it allowed access to every call no matter the tags (even if X is not present).

I don't know what i am missing, does Dynamo even supports tagging access restrictions?
Am i doing something wrong?
Thanks

Comment: DynamoDB doesn't support tag-based  conditions, see [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/specifying-conditions.html)

Comment: @shuvalov you should add your comment as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the [DynamoDB documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/specifying-conditions.html), and per @[shuvalov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/272749/shuvalov)'s comment, DynamoDB does not support tag based conditions.

It is explicitly stated in the docs.

> Some AWS services also support tag-based conditions; however, DynamoDB does not.

The [Service Authorization Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/reference.html) can be used to view condition keys that are supported by each AWS service.

Comment: I had a similar problem with another service, SSM Parameter Store.  Going through the Service Authorization Reference above it seems that commands that can be controlled using tags as in the AWS docs are the exception, not the rule.